# FFmpeg 2017 vs 2019 decoding performance improvement

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-capture, decoding

I was trying to do some basic profiling on `ffmpeg`, following my previous question  [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1464184). I have a relatively high-bitrate .ts file (17mbps), and I have two versions of ffmpeg (2017.3 and 2019.4), and tried to run a decoding process (blackdetect filter) on both of them. I notice the 2019 version is at least 2.2 times faster. More especifically, execution of the following command takes 2.2x faster on the 2019 version:

```
ffmpeg -i in.ts -vf blackdetect=d=0.1:pix_th=.1 -f rawvideo -y null
```

Is this really expected? Is there a known, major performance improvement on ffmpeg that wasn't there in 2017 version? If that's really the case, updating my ffmpeg core should really make it run faster!

**EDIT:** 
File is H264 encoded, but relatively higher bitrate. I actually compiled both `ffmpeg` versions from source code with same build options. If it is decoding improvement, that's something very interesting.

The 2019 `ffmpeg` command output:

```
ffmpeg version N-94171-g0cbdedb Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/home/user/usr/local --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.101 / 58. 53.101
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 56.100 /  7. 56.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

And the 2017 output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=bin --bindir=bin
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

**EDIT 2:**

Full log for `ffmpeg -i in.ts -t 100 -benchmark -an -f null -`: [2019](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9skp82wd4qkplr7/2019.txt?dl=0) and [2017](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zt2xc3xpbf6vb5w/2017.txt?dl=0)

Comment: This is very vague question. FFmpeg get various performance improvements all the time. You haven't provided enough info to answer you question.

Comment: Added the command. Curious why we see this huge improvement.

Comment: The blackdetect filter haven't changed much at all in that period. Maybe file have codecs which decoders are received major speed improvements. Or it is build issue, for example one build was compiled with asm support and other haven't. For more info post ffmpeg output of both builds.

Comment: File is H264, but high bitrate. I actually compiled both versions from source code with same build options. If it is decoding improvement, that's something I'd be interested.

Comment: Please show ffmpeg output of both builds.

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol Builds you mean just the `configure` outputs, or also all the `make` outputs?

Comment: Just what ffmpeg output when its run without arguments.

Comment: oh ok...wait a second...

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol just added those details.

Comment: And this is all tested on same machine?

Comment: Yes. Everything the same.

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol any updates?

Comment: How do you measure speed improvements?

Comment: Total time to decode. Also, there is a `speed:2.5x` notation on ffmpeg when decoding.

Comment: And for 2017 version speed is 1.25x?

Comment: Well, i meant if speed for 2017 was whatever, the same for 2019 was 2.2x more (I think maybe 2 vs 4.6 or something)

Comment: I do not think version from 2017. have speed indicator so I wonder how you measure speed.

Comment: Share full log for `ffmpeg -i in.ts -t 100 -benchmark -an -f null -` with both versions.

Comment: @Gyan Added those full logs in revised question.